# Smoke simulation through small gaps

Tags: smoke-simulation

I would like to do a smoke simulation which pass through the gap between two planes. Planes are set as *Effector* and *Effector Type* as *Collision*. The smokes will pass when there is a considerable gap between the two planes. When I reduce gap width the smoke wont pass. I changed the value of *Surface Thickness* of *Effector* but it didnt work. Is there any method to make smoke pass through small gaps?

[image]

Comment: the small rectangle in the corner of the domain is the "resolution cube". Everything which is smaller than that won't take into account. So just increase the domain resolution and you can make your gaps smaller.

Comment: @Chris Thanks alot. Will try

Comment: @Chris Thank You. It worked

Comment: glad i could help